# Opening an pdf file without print and save buttons - php

Tags: php

I want pdf view in browser but user cannot download, save or print that file. I don't want to use build-in of browser. I want it in php or jquery, js..

Comment: @Testing How can that be a dup? OP want's user to be unable to print.

Comment: Why do you want to do this

Comment: Show content as html. Then disable default operations of right click, crtl + c, crtl + p and crtl+ s.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  All files reside on the client machine the user can do what they like with them.

Comment: A very good point. Even if you don't have a save button, any tech savvy user will know where the browser's cache is and can copy the file from there.